# "Account currency" translation

Tags: meaning, translation

I'm not a native English speaker and I'd like to translate the following sentence:

"Here you can see your Account Terms including the freight and payment terms, minimum order value, and account currency."

Could you please explain what "account currency" is?

I would translate it as a type of an account which accepts payments in different currencies, but I'm not sure if that's true.

Is it a type of an account which accepts all kinds of currencies?

Is it the currency ($, €) that's used in the account?

Is it an expression that describes the account in any way?

Comment: It's the currency which that particular account uses (banks can provide *Dollar accounts, Sterling accounts, Yen accounts* and so on).

Comment: I see nothing on the supplied list of commonly available references that would help a reader answer this question. It should be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means the currency the account is recorded in.